# Not to include unnecessary rails resource routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller named `foo`, controller and model named `bar`. `foo` is just a controller, no model. With `foo`, I have a route: `/foo`. In the routes I have:

```
resources :bar
```

I need something like

```
/foo/bar/ # new, edit, create, update etc
```

I can do this with:

```
resource :foo do
  resources :bar
end
```

Doing so will end up having `dashboard create, update etc` and I dont want all those routes.

Is there a simple way, without the unnecessary routes, to have

```
/foo/bar/new
/foo/bar/edit
# with all methods: post, patch etc?
```

Comment: [Look at the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined in the [official guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created), You can use `only` and `except` as options to restrict the actions for which routes are to be generated:

```
resource :foo, only: [:index] do # exception/inclusion before the do block
   resources :bars
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you ..

Please refer Shallow Nesting section of below url

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html